# Website structure with Craft

Tags: structure

This is my first try at Craft, was planning on replicating a current site as practice, had a question about the sites architecture.

I have a Brands page:

```
Brand/Company info
-Brand product line
--individual products within that line
```

What would be the best way to implement this? 
I'm thinking a structure? They are child's of each other?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably have products as a channel and then a product being tied to a category so and then category urls would be something like `/products/category`

Answer (score 4):

Steven's answer is great and it allows you to do clever things with faceted search and filtering later on. Don't forget that Categories can also make use of custom fields which is helpful if you want to build a Category 'home page'.

Another route is to leverage Crafts Relationships capability.

If both **Products** and **Brands** were **Channels**, then you can add an Entries customer field within you Products Entry Type - so that when you publish a product, you get to define which Brand it is related to.

This would allow you to relate other Sections / content-types to a **Brand** as well.

Ultimately, there are a million ways to skin this cat, I suggest taking into account the requirements for the entire project and how they may evolve and deciding on a project by project basis.